# 'python -m unittest discover' works locally but unable to discover tests on CircleCi

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest, circleci-2.0

I am trying to add unittests to my project on CircleCi. Locally, when I run 'python -m unittest discover' from terminal, its able to find and run all 16 tests. But on CircleCi, it says:

```
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
```

Any idea as to what might be going on?? 
Is there some configuration or environment variable that I am missing??

My project structure:

```
project
├── src
│   ├── main
│       ├── python
│           ├── testing
│               ├──Test1.py
|               ├──Test2.py
```

config.yml

```
version: 2
docker:
  - image: circleci/python:3.7.5
jobs:
  build:
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: deps1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "requirements.txt" }}
      - run:
          name: Install Python deps in a venv
          command: |
            python3 -m venv venv
            . venv/bin/activate
            pip install -r requirements/dev.txt
      - save_cache:
          key: deps1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "requirements.txt" }}
          paths:
          - "venv"
      - run:
          name: Running tests
          command: |
            cd ~/project/src/main/python/testing/
            python3 -m unittest discover
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally soved this.
My test classes started with a capital 'T' and unittest by default looks for `test*.py`. So I had to add additional configuration as shown below:

```
python -m unittest discover -p "Test*.py"
```

Locally it was able to discover the tests as the Windows commandline is not case-sensitive.
But the Linux commandline that CircleCi spins up, is case-sensitive and that is why the tests were not getting discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `working_directory` for that particular step, rather than using `cd`, e.g.

```
- run:
    name: Running tests
    working_directory: ~/project/src/main/python/testing/
    command: |
        python3 -m unittest discover
```